# Turning off unittest execution of third-party code

Tags: linux, unit-testing, compilation, d

I'm trying to understand how the '-unittest' dmd switch can be used to select which files have their unittests executed.

I have a file, "a.d", containing a unittest block. File "a.d" imports from a third-party module (requiring the file "b1.d" and in turn "b2.d") which contain their own unittest blocks.

I don't want to run the tests in the third-party code: I just want to run the tests in a.d.

If I compile the third-party code first

```
dmd -c b1.d b2.d
```

then try to link it with my code with the unittests copied in

```
dmd -unittest a.d b1.o b2.o
```

then I get an error saying that the module in b1.d which a.d is trying to import is in a file that cannot be read.

Can anyone show me how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible because **a.d** has imported **b1.d** and **b2.d**. It means that those modules must be passed to the compiler.

If you want to link some ***.o** files it's more complex: you have to write an interface (*.di file for them just like for a ***.so**) thus it's not a good idea to use this mechanism to bypass the unittests. (although this could work it's a bit heavy).

A more straightforward way to arbitrary select some unittests is to use the trait [**getUnitTests**](http://dlang.org/traits#getUnitTests). It's really more the way to go.

Comment: Doesn't getUnitTests still depend on using the -unittest switch, hence I'm still faced with compiling in all the unittests from b1.d and b2.d?

Comment: It does but you can write a function to select the tests in a.d and run them, I mean exclusively. Look at the example in the documentation.

Comment: Your Q is *Turning off unittest **execution** of third-party* not *Turning off unittest **compilation** of third-party*.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Just use separate compilation and linking steps, i.e.

```
dmd -c -unittest a.d
```

and then:

```
dmd a.o b1.o b2.o
```

That's it.

Comment: That doesn't compile because a.d imports from b1.d, which in turn imports b2.d.